# Undeleted object value is null after Core Data saving context

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have an object which has `objectId` and `objectName` attributes. After I deleting an item from using Core Data's `deleteObject` function and saving the context, the object's value is null even though I only used the object for a predicate. Here's my code.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.theObject.name); // it returns the object's name

NSError *error = nil;        
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectId==%@", self.theObject.objectId];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

NSArray *myObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (MyClass *myObject in myObjects) {
    [context deleteObject:myObject];
}

if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.theObject.name); // it returns null
}
```

Is it a default behaviour of Core Data, or did I miss something? Why is `theObject`'s value null when I only used it for predicate?

**Edit based on comment**

`theObject` is set from the parent view controller within `prepareForSegue` method.

```
destinationViewController.theObject = self.theObjectsArray[indexPath.row];
```

I logged `theObject` value in `viewDidLoad` and it was set successfully.

Comment: it looks like you delete the object in your context that has theObject ID... which should be theObject ... ?!

Comment: @Volker I just used theObject's ID for predicate, and filled myObjects array with the request. I deleted only myObject (which is MyClass), but theObject's value is null after saving the context. It's so confusing. P.S. myObject and theObject are different class.

Comment: so if theObject shows null there must be some reason, it doesn't happen magically. Maybe you give more details how you create theObject. By using it in a predicate its values won't get reset to NULL

Comment: theObject was set from the parent view controller by prepareForSegue like destinationViewController.theObject = self.theObjectsArray[indexPath.row]; I logged theObject value in viewDidLoad and it was set successfully.

Comment: Best to add this information as edit to your question. Also add how you derive theObject. Is it also loaded from your context? If yes, why shouldn't it be deleted when you perform the deletion you show above?

Comment: @Volker's last comment is right if the condition holds. So, what's your goal?

Comment: Your code is kind of confusing. Is `theObject` different than `self.theObject`? Also, `objectId` is a terrible name for a managed object property, since `NSManagedObject` already has an `objectID` of its own.

Comment: It shouldn't be nulled, because the user can insert this object from the same screen after pressing delete button. I didn't use objectId in my code, just refactored names for an example. Yes, theObject and self.theObject are same. I fixed it in the question.

Comment: Deleted my answer because, while it fits your code, you explained again that there arrested are critical details that you did not include in your question. You don't have any answers yet because you keep leaving out crucial, relevant facts relating to the question.

Comment: It is not the object that is nil, it's the property. You have just *deleted* the object from the context and committed it, but you still have a pointer to it. Thus, the object's properties are nil - you deleted it and saved that change.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: yes, that's how it works.

In order to explain, I'll need to first assume that theObject is a managed object in core data.  As such it inherits from NSManagedObjecctID which is what gives you the ability to query it by objectId.

You can think of theObject as a pointer to a managed object in the managed object context. The id is what makes that object 100% unique in the given context.

So when you make a request for that object, core data is going to give you back theObject because you requested theObject using its id.

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html

Core data doesn't return you some copy of the object you requested (in which case it would be a different pointer, but the same data), it returns the particular instance you requested.